# Dynamic Module Python

Tags: python, module

I have a program that creates a module called "cool" using file operations. I later say `import cool` and then uses the `cool` module that was created.

Here is my directory

```
project/
    main.py
    modules/
        maker.py
        cool/          #this folder and its contents was made by maker.py
            __init__.py 
            coolm.py
```

If I want to make my program into the `.exe` format, this strategy will not work anymore. Does anyone know another technique?

Note: I cannot use `exec` to use the `cool` module..

Comment: Where is the failure occurring?  Writing out the module?  Importing it?  Somewhere else?

Comment: Dynamically creating a module doesn't seem like a good idea, considering if anyone were to use your code running several processes at the same time, you might not get the version of the module you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Import your module when you need it like this:

```
coolmod = __import__('coolm')
coolm.someproperty
```

Alternatively you could try:

```
import importlib
coolmod = importlib.import_module('coolm', 'cool')
```

This allows you to specify the package name as a second argument.